# How to run a conditional correlation in excel with multiple conditions?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to run a conditional correlation across a year and the conditions need to be with time and month. For example, I want to find correlation of apple stock price in month 1 hour 1 with intel stock price in month 1 hour 1.

I need to do this for every hour for every month so 288 correlations. I can't figure out how to automate it. It needs to be in excel as well. It can use VBA but preferably not.

This is what I have tried so far

```
=correl( if(v$5=1 AND $w4=1),$e1:$e8760),if(v$5=1 AND $w4=1),$f1:$f8760))
```

The problem is it keeps calculating correlation between all of `e` and all of `f` instead of the subsets of `e` and `f` that pertain to the conditions.

Any suggestions would help!

Comment: Are you expecting someone to write this for you? We're happy to help answer questions, but this isn't a code-writing service. If you have some code and a question about it, post & ask that. Show us what you've started

Comment: sorry first time using this. This is the code I have rn =correl( if(v$5=1 AND  $w4=1),$e1:$e8760),if(v$5=1 AND  $w4=1),$f1:$f8760))

Comment: problem is it keeps calculating correlation between all of e and all of f instead of the subsets of e and f that pertain to the conditions

Comment: Please edit your post and add that code (in code formatting, look for `{}` symbol), and add that info as well.

Comment: i tried using the brackets as well like you suggested, and it didnt work. I pressed controls +shift+enter instead of a normal enter and it still didnd't work